# Efficient computation of greatest power of 2 < x

Tags: c, math

I have a requirement to compute the greatest power of 2 which is < an integer value, x

currently I am using:

```
#define log2(x) log(x)/log(2)
#define round(x) (int)(x+0.5)

x = round(pow(2,(ceil(log2(n))-1)));
```

this is in a performance critical function

Is there a more computationally efficient way of calculating x?

Comment: up to how high?  It might be easier to have a fixed lookup table for at least some common range.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have an integer log2 function in my c-libutl library (hosted on googlecode if anyone is interested)

```
/*
** Integer log base 2 of a 32 bits integer values.
**   llog2(0) == llog2(1) == 0
*/
unsigned short llog2(unsigned long x)
{
  long l = 0;

  x &= 0xFFFFFFFF /* just in case 'long' is more than 32bit */

  if (x==0) return 0;

  #ifndef UTL_NOASM
    #if defined(__POCC__) || defined(_MSC_VER) || defined (__WATCOMC__)
        /* Pelles C            MS Visual C++         OpenWatcom */
      __asm { mov eax, [x]
              bsr ecx, eax
              mov  l, ecx
      }
    #elif defined(__GNUC__)
      l = (unsigned short) ((sizeof(long)*8 -1) - __builtin_clzl(x));
    #else
      #define UTL_NOASM
    #endif  
  #endif

  #ifdef UTL_NOASM  /* Make a binary search.*/
    if (x & 0xFFFF0000) {l += 16; x >>= 16;} /* 11111111111111110000000000000000 */
    if (x & 0xFF00)     {l += 8;  x >>= 8 ;} /* 1111111100000000*/
    if (x & 0xF0)       {l += 4;  x >>= 4 ;} /* 11110000*/
    if (x & 0xC)        {l += 2;  x >>= 2 ;} /* 1100 */
    if (x & 2)          {l += 1;  }          /* 10 */
    return l;
  #endif

  return (unsigned short)l;
}
```

Then you can simply compute

```
 (1 << llog2(x))
```

to compute the greatest power of two that is less than x. Beware 0! You should handle it separately.

It uses assembler code but can also be forced to plain C code by defining the UTL_NOASM symbol.

The code has been tested at the time but it's quite some time I don't use it and I can't say if it behaves in a 64-bit environment.

Comment: this looks super efficient - thanks for the heads up on your library

Comment: Please note that the library is alpha and in constant rework. Though some code snippet may be useful.

Answer (score 3):

You are essentially looking for the highest non-zero bit in your number. Many processors have built-in instructions for this, which in turn are exposed by many compilers. For example, in GCC I would look at [`__builtin_clz`](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html), which

> Returns the number of leading 0-bits in `x`, starting at the most significant bit position.

Together with `sizeof(int) * CHAR_BIT` and a shift, you can use this to figure out the corresponding pure-power-of-two integer. There's also a version for long integers.

(The CPU instruction is presumably called "CLZ" (count leading zeros), in case you need to look this up for other compilers.)

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Bit Twiddling Hacks: Find the log base 2 of an N-bit integer in O(lg(N)) operations](http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#IntegerLog) by Sean Eron Anderson (code contributed by Eric Cole and Andrew Shapira):

```c
unsigned int highest_bit (uint32_t v) {
    unsigned int r = 0, s;
    s = (v > 0xFFFF) << 4; v >>= s; r |= s;
    s = (v > 0xFF  ) << 3; v >>= s; r |= s;
    s = (v > 0xF   ) << 2; v >>= s; r |= s;
    s = (v > 0x3   ) << 1; v >>= s; r |= s;
    return r | (v >> 1);
}
```

This returns the index of the highest bit of the input; the greatest power of 2 no greater than the input is then `1 << highest_bit(x)`, and the greatest power of 2 strictly less than the input is thus simply `1 << highest_bit(x-1)`.

For 64-bit inputs, just change the input type to `uint64_t` and add the following extra line at the beginning of the function, after the variable declarations:

```
    s = (v > 0xFFFFFFFF) << 8; v >>= s; r |= s;
```

Answer (score 0):

Shifting bits around will most likely be much faster. Probably some bisection method on bits could make it even faster. Nice exercise for an improvement.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int closestPow2(int x)
{
        int     p;

        if (x <= 1) return 0; /* No such power exists */

        x--;   /* Account for exact powers of 2, then one power less must be returned */
        for (p = 0; x > 0; p++)
        {
                x >>= 1;
        }

        return 1<<(p-1);
}

int main(void)
{
        printf("%x\n", closestPow2(0x7FFFFFFF));
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Left and right shift operators do this the best

```
int MaxPowerOf2(int x)
{
   int out = 1;
   while(x > 1) { x>>1; out<<1;}
   return out;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <math.h>  

double greatestPower( double x )  
{  
    return floor(log( x ) / log( 2 ));  
}
```

That is true since `log` in monotony increasing function.